# Implementing TLS server/client using book "Implementing SSL / TLS Using Cryptography and PKI" by Joshua Davies

Tags: c, ssl, https, md5, sha

I was implementing an HTTPS client/server example just for learning purpose using the book "Implementing SSL / TLS Using Cryptography and PKI" by Joshua Davies. It contains an example implementation with C source code. I just tried to build a HTTPS client using that source code. But, in tls.c file it uses two macros `MD5_BYTE_SIZE` and `SHA1_BYTE_SIZE` and I can't see any values defined for these macros in that book. I tried with permutations of 16,24,32 for both macros but failed in SSL handshaking, and greater values causes segmentation fault. I hope if anybody familiar with this book can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The publisher keeps two source bundles for the book: [GCC](https://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/16/04709204/DOWNLOAD/920411%20implementing_ssl_gcc.zip) and [VS](https://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/16/04709204/DOWNLOAD/920411%20implementing_ssl_vs.zip).

From {before,after}/ch04/sha.h:

```
#define SHA1_RESULT_SIZE 5
#define SHA1_BYTE_SIZE SHA1_RESULT_SIZE * sizeof( int )
```

From {before,after}/ch04/md5.h:

```
#define MD5_RESULT_SIZE 4
#define MD5_BYTE_SIZE MD5_RESULT_SIZE * sizeof( int )
```